# Java Client for JSON RPC 2.0 over RabbitMQ

Tags: json, json-rpc

I need to write a Java JSON-RPC client that will communicate over RabbitMQ. All the implementations I've found assumed HTTP as the transport, and that won't work for me. RabbitMQ has it's own RPC client/server, but it's JSON-RPC 1.1, not 2.0.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JSON-RPC is just a communications protocol based on JSON; JSON is just some UTF-16 text. JSON-RPC is therefore transport protocol-agostic (i.e: the JSON-RPC specification only concerns itself with the ***CONTENT*** of messages).

A JSON-RPC "webservice" is necessarily transported via HTTP(s). However, a JSON-RPC "server" can use almost any transport (e.g: raw TCP, SMTP, etc).

You could have a simple line-oriented (process a message when you see a newline) TCP server, and as long as the request is JSON-RPC formatted, and the reply is JSON-RPC formatted, then that is a JSON-RPC "server". If your transport protocol has the ability to receive and send [UCS-2/UTF-16](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding) then you can implement JSON-RPC over it.

Folks have already implemented JSON-RPC over "comet", websockets, webRTC, etc.

Some parts of the JSON-RPC 2.0 protocol are easier to implement over certain transports. For example, if your transport doesn't have simultaneous bi-directional communication (e.g: HTTP or HTTPs) then you can only implement a simplified version of the "notification" message. Instead of the "server" sending notification messages to the client whenever it pleases, either it piggy-backs "notification" messages on RPC-style replies (perhaps using "batch" messages), or the client itself "polls" the server for "notification" messages.

RabbitMQ has a plugin called [web-stomp](http://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html) which implements websockets so that web browsers can communicate with RabbitMQ using JavaScript. If your target client is a web-browser <strike>and you don't need asynchronous notification support,</strike> you could easily send JSON-RPC messages over the websockets polyfill provided by web-stomp.

If your client language can already talk to RabbitMQ natively, then you simply encode the UTF-16 into something publishable by RabbitMQ and and decode them on the other side.

**EDIT:**  Of course, websockets *are* asynchronous, and you *can* implement proper "notification" style messages over them.